# Login Allow only 3 attemts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am creating a new application..
I created a login page successfully..
Now I need to modify the login page ..
Only 3 attempts only allowed for a user ..
If the user wrongly enters the password more than 3 times(within 5 min) his account must be blocked..And error message must be shown as You cant access your page

my database table like this
empid|   empusername emppassword  Isblocked  empdescripton

---

i want also query provide me 
pls can any one help me pls.....................................

pls help me can any one..................................

Comment: Some research is required on your part. How to get a login failed has probably been covered a thousand times.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Membership Provider, just set `MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts` to 3.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx

> The MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts property works in conjunction with the
>   PasswordAttemptWindow property to guard against an unwanted source
>   guessing the password or password answer of a membership user through
>   repeated attempts. If the number of invalid passwords or password
>   questions supplied for a membership user is greater than or equal to
>   the MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts property value within the number of
>   minutes identified by the PasswordAttemptWindow, then the membership
>   user is locked out by setting the IsLockedOut property to true until
>   the user is unlocked by a call to the UnlockUser method. If a valid
>   password or password answer is supplied before the
>   MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts value is reached, the counter that tracks
>   the number of invalid attempts is reset to zero.